# Is Firebase having problems with executing functions inside setTimeout callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am coding a Node.js/ExpressJS server to which I've added Firebase-admin SDK.

The server is now under heavy development, so a significant part of it's functionalities are mocked by sort of 'simulations'. This case is about that the server will receive a request from a client saying that the client wants a window blind to go up or down.

The flow is:

The server then sends a request to the blind saying that it should go in specified direction. Right after that, server updates the blind's movement state in Firebase's realtime database. When the blind goes all the way up or down, it sends a request back to the server, saying that the movement has been finished. Then the server updates Firebase's realtime database with the new state (like `CLOSED` or `OPENED`).

As I mentioned before, this functionality is mocked too, so the blind's movement is actually handled by a `setTimeout` function which 'simulates' each blind's movement to last 10 seconds. After the 'movement' is finished, the `setTimeout` function changes `blindState` to `CLOSED` or `OPENED` state appropriately, which is supposed to simulate the blind's response that will be sent to the server in the future.

I want to keep the Firebase's realtime database updated with the `blindState` value for each blind. So after the blind has 'finished moving' I also want to send updated data to firebase. There seems to be a problem with that. The value of `blindStateRef` is `"test/devicesStates/blindStateRef"`. Names of the objects in this path will be the IDs of the blinds. Each blind will have a field called `state` containing information whether the blind is `OPENED`, `CLOSED` or `MOVING`.

When I try to update the database I get an error saying `Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "5a5106f0144ad2bf792a9eda". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Is it caused because of the fact, that it is called inside `setTimeout` function?

This is the call:

```
const blindMovementFunction = (blind, direction) => setTimeout((blind, direction) => {
    if (direction === "UP") {
        blindState = "OPENED";

        blindStateRef.child(blind._id).set({
            state: blindState
        });

        blind.state = blindState;
        blind.save();
    } else if (direction === "DOWN") {
        blindState = "CLOSED";

        blindStateRef.child(blind._id).set({
            state: blindState
        });

        blind.state = blindState;
        blind.save();
    }
}, 10000, blind, direction);
```

Comment: Log the value of `blind._id`.  That's what it's complaining about.  The fact that setTimeout is involved should make no difference.

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, I tried that. The ID is there and it has the right value. I have no idea what can be firebase complaining about in this case

Comment: What is the right value?

Comment: @DougStevenson The right value is `5a5106f0144ad2bf792a9eda`, which is the same as displayed in the error message. that is why i am so confused

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

Instead of pulling the `_id` field from the `blind` object, I refactored the `blindMovementFunction` to tak 3 arguments and added `blindId` there.

`blindId` is exactly `blind._id`, but the value is passed directly to the function while it's being invoked. `blind._id` had the right value inside the function though.

No idea why did it start working, but I will leave this information here for future reference for people who stumbled across a similar problem